# Changing Thickness of one link out of several links in shape file.

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

I have created a shape file with some links between nodes using java program. Now I want to change the thickness of one of the link (or line).

I mean in a shape file, I want to create some lines with (1.0f basic stroke ) and another with (2.of basic stroke). 
How Can I do that?

Thank in advance for your time and help.